# JAVA exception getMessage() method calling constructor

Tags: java, exception

```
public class TestException extends Exception
{
    public TestException()
    {
        super("Test Exception 1 thrown!");
        System.out.println("Test Exception 2 thrown!");
    }
...
}
```

In another place, I have code like this:

```
TestException exceptionObject = new TestException();
System.out.println(exceptionObject.getMessage());
```

I prints out the result as follows:

```
Test Exception 2 thrown!
Test Exception 1 thrown!
```

Could you kindly tell me why does the output of the `println` method come first?

Comment: i think you shuld debug you code before you ask the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you construct the exception (by calling `new TestException()`), which sets the message property of Exception to "Test Exception 1 thrown!", but doesn't print it, and prints "Test Exception 2 thrown!".

Then you print the value of `getMessage()`, by calling `System.out.println(exceptionObject.getMessage());`. This prints "Test Exception 1 thrown!"

Hence the output you got.

BTW, just to make it clear, regardless of the messages you printed, no exception is being thrown here.